# Heritage and Inheritance

Tags: difference

Could someone please explain to me what is the difference in meaning between heritage and inheritance and give an example of each? Thank you

Comment: This is an interesting question, and I hope you ask some more. That said, it would be nice if you expounded a little bit on what you already understand, and where you are still confused (that way, people won't spend time explaining something that your already know). For more about this feel free to have a look at [this question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439), along with some of the answers there as well. Welcome aboard!

Comment: A related (but not duplicate) question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17769/what-is-the-difference-between-legacy-and-inheritance

Comment: It's amazing the number of random answers –deleted and none–posted by 1 rep users who then go on to disappear.

Answer (score 8):

Both "heritage" and "inheritance" refer to things that you get from your parents or ancestors or others you have some association with, after their deaths. "Inheritance", when used literally, refers to money, real estate, or other tangible property. "Heritage" refers to intangible things, like ideals, knowledge, and moral standards.

For example, you might say, "My inheritance from my grandfather included $50,000 and a house in Virginia." But, "Our founding fathers left us a heritage of liberty and justice."

The verb "inherit" can be used for either idea. "I inherited my father's antique car collection." Or, "I inherited my father's love of baseball."

Comment: Or genetics: _I inherited my mother's blue eyes_.

Comment: "Heritage" can be used even if the people you got it from are still alive: "My parents have taught me a lot about my Hungarian heritage."

Comment: @Martha You could quibble over that. In your example, your "Hungarian heritage" may have been taught to you by your mother, but she didn't "create" it -- that heritage is something passed down over many generations. Like if I say, "My teacher taught me calculus", I don't suppose that means the teacher invented it. If I said, "My family as a heritage of working in aviation", when the only person before me who worked in aviation was my father and he's still alive ... maybe, but I don't think most people would say that.

Comment: @J.R. "or genetics": Quite true. Might be other things one could "inherit" too -- anything that you get from parents or mentors or other associated people.

Answer (score 0):

***Heritage*** is something that comes or belongs to one by reason of birth or ***heritage*** can refer to practices that are passed down through the years, from one generation to the next. While ***Inheritance*** is something that has quality, characteristics, or other immaterial possession, received from progenitors or predecessors.

Answer (score 0):

I think heritage is deeper in meaning. It really has to do with the ideals, morals, way of living, godly or otherwise attributes passed down the line from one generation to another, while inheritance could mean material things inherited or equally passed down the line. Joshua passed down heritage in Joshua 24:15b. That was good.

Answer (score 0):

By reason of birth do you possess a **Heritage**, by reason of death do you possess an **Inheritance**.  Both **Heritage** and **Inheritance** can be material or immaterial possessions (the sun, moon, and stars are a heritage), but there is a more etheral quality to your **Heritage** and a more concrete quality to your **Inheritance**.

Answer (score 0):

heritage is any property that is inherited from the past.
heritage comes in different form  natural  and cultural heritage.
the natural features like the sun, moon and any natural feature you know.
cultural  heritage can be intangible and tangible.
the tangibility of cultural heritage centres on our experiencial source of knowledge.
that is things we see, touch etc.
so is food heritage?
yes what ever may be the case, tangible heritage can be seen in our cultures.
our  dresses, food ect. are all tangible heritage.
thank you.